# Equivalence of norms on a basis

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove something and I have two norms $||\cdot||$, $|||\cdot|||$ over some finite dimensional space $X$ spanned by $x_1, \cdots, x_n$. I know that
$$||x_i|| \leq K\, |||x_i||| \, \forall i=1, \cdots, n$$
My question is if it is possible to bound in terms of $K$ the constant $C$ (which exists because the two norms are equivalent) such that
$$||x|| \leq C \,|||x||| \, \forall x \in X$$

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: The constant $K$ trivially exists as you could take $K=\text{max}\{\dfrac{||x_i||}{|||x_i|||}, i=1,\ldots,n \}$. I don't think one can find such a bound.

Comment: By equivalence of norms you have, for another constant

$$||x_i|| \leq K\, |||x_i|||\le L||x_i|| $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In $\Bbb{R}^2$, let $x_1 = (1,0)$ and $x_2 = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ for some small $\theta$. In the standard norm, $x_1, x_2$ are unit vectors, and $\|x_1-x_2\|$ is small. However, there exists a (unique) inner product such that $x_1, x_2$ form an orthonormal basis, and with respect to this induced norm, $x_1-x_2$ has norm $\sqrt{2}$ by the Pythagorean theorem. By making $\theta$ small, we make the constant for the equivalence of norms as big as we want, despite $x_1, x_2$ being the same size in both norms.